# Convergence of $\sum{{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Convergence of $\sum{{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})}}$ where n={1,2,3...}

Can't think of a different method. Please help

Comment: Test 0: Do the terms converge to $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer i think limit doesn't exist as $n-> \infty$ right ?

Comment: What is your reason to think that?

Comment: sine function oscillates between -1 to 1 and maintains this as input becomes large

Comment: Okay, that's a pretty good reason to expect that the sequence $\sin \frac{\pi n}{3}$ doesn't converge. Have you an idea how you could _prove_ it?

Comment: Till now all I can only say that the limit doesn't exist so series is divergent but if you can give me some link (for better explaination) to read I'll be glad

Comment: So far we haven't yet proved that $\sin \frac{n\pi}{3}$ doesn't converge to $0$. We have reason to believe it doesn't, but we need a proof. Have you looked at the first few values?

Comment: $(\sqrt(3)/2,\sqrt(3)/2,0,\sqrt(3)/2,\sqrt(3)/2,0....)$

Comment: There are some minus signs missing. And you stop right where one could notice a pattern. The sequence is periodic, $\sin \frac{(n+6)\pi}{3} = \sin \frac{n\pi}{3}$. And since it isn't constant, it follows that the sequence doesn't converge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58731/discussion-between-vishweshwar-tyagi-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: @DanielFischer actually the original question in my paper is $\sum{{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})}^n}$ so I take mod then nth root and hence for the missing negative signs. But I got your point and it really helped. Thanks

Comment: Then a comparison with $\bigl(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigr)^n$ nails it, it's absolutely convergent. But since the answers here refer to the version without the exponent, it's not good to change the question now. Please revert to the original question.

Comment: Done and thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

$\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})$ does not converge to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0):

If a series converge then $S_N=\sum\limits_{n=0}^N a_n\to L$, but $a_n=S_N-S_{N-1}\to L-L=0$.

So it is mandatory that $a_n\to 0$ in order to have a convergent series.

Here $a_n=\sin(\frac{n\pi}3)$ and in particular $a_{6k+1}=\sin(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{3})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\nrightarrow 0$

If any subsequence, does not converge to zero, then $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ and the series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the fact that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty} a_n.$$
Knowing that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\dfrac{n \pi}{3}\right)}$ converges $\Longleftrightarrow$ the partial sum converges, we can create a sequence $(s_n)$ to be the sequence of partial sum. Since
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n = \sqrt{3} \text{ and } \liminf_{n \to \infty} s_n = 0,$$
thus we can conclude that the series diverges.